# Scale a Bitmap in function of the angle in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, scale, angle

I want to draw arrow in ellipse shape, almost like [here](http://www.localwisdom.com/blog/2013/10/creating-custom-view-android/), but I'd like to scale the arrow in function of the angle: reduce the arrow when the radius is low, and increase it when the ratius is big.

The code is:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

            int centerX = (viewBitmapWidth / 2) - (bitmap.getWidth() / 2);
            int centerY = (viewBitmapHeight / 2) - (bitmap.getHeight());

            matrix.reset();


    double angle = Math.atan2(
        radiusx * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / elements.length),
        radiusy * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i / elements.length));

    matrix.postRotate((float) (angle * 180 / Math.PI),
        (float) (bitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 5 * Math.sin(angle)),
        (float) (bitmap.getHeight() + 5 * Math.cos(angle)));

    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);

    Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
        bitmap.getWidth(), (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * Math.sin(angle)), false);

    canvas.drawBitmap(tempBitmap, matrix, null);`
```

but I obtain this error:

> 08-29 22:10:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1053): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
>   08-29 22:10:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1053): at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:638)
>   08-29 22:10:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1053): at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:586)
>   08-29 22:10:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1053): at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:466)
>   08-29 22:10:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1053): at com.turvy.organicreaction.views.CircleView.onDraw(CircleView.java:156)
>   08-29 22:10:29.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1053): at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13458)ivityThread.java:4745)
>   ...

I've also tried the postScale or preScale methods of the matrix, but it was'nt good, it changed everything, even the position.

Could you help me with my problem, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception says that you're creating a Bitmap with height or width < 0. So use the following to create the Bitmap:

```
Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), 
    (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * Math.abs(Math.sin(angle))), false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did'nt take care about the negative value of sinus. In addition, I had to change the formula (for ex: 100 +  bitmap.getHeight() * Math.abs(Math.sin(angle))) since sinus can also be equal to 0